# What does char* assignment do?

Tags: c, char

I have a char* and I'm assigning another char* to it. I want to know what all is going to happen through that instruction?

For example:

```
char* foo; // suppose it is initialized and defined

char* bar = foo // I am defining bar
```

What all would happen(to foo and bar) after calling the assignment operation wrt values, memory etc.

I am new to C, maybe very trivial question for some of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say we have two pointers initialized to point to different strings:

```
const char *foo = "abcd";
const char *bar = "efgh";
```

If we "draw" how they would look in memory, it would be something like this:

```
+-----+      +--------+
| foo | ---> | "abcd" |
+-----+      +--------+

+-----+      +--------+
| bar | ---> | "efgh" |
+-----+      +--------+
```

Then we assign to `bar`:

```
bar = foo;
```

Then it would look something like this instead:

```
+-----+      +--------+
| foo | -+-> | "abcd" |
+-----+  |   +--------+
         |
+-----+  |   +--------+
| bar | -/   | "efgh" |
+-----+      +--------+
```

Now both `foo` and `bar` are pointing to the same location.

In shorter form, that's what a definition with initialization like:

```
const char *bar = foo;
```

will do.

Comment: note: the arrows don't actually exist in the computer

Answer (score 1):

In, `char* bar = foo`, the `= foo` is technically an initialization, not an assignment. Initialization follows many of the rules of assignment.

Since `foo` is a pointer to `char`, and you say it has been initialized, it has a “value” that is a reference to some `char` object (or a null pointer). We often think of these values as addresses in computer memory. The initialization or assignment merely gives `bar` the same value.

Values are represented with bytes. So, to record the value of `foo`, there are some bytes in the memory reserved for `foo`. To set `bar` to the same value, all the compiler has to do is copy the bytes from the memory of `foo` to the memory of `bar`.